# Hikari connection pooling + Hibernate 4.3.8 + Spring Data JPA configuration?

Tags: spring, hibernate, connection-pooling, hikaricp

please tell me.
How can I configure the "Hikari connection pooling + Hibernate 4.3.8 + Spring Data JPA configuration"?
Here is my configuration, but for some reason I am sure that this configuration is not correct. Because the the console does not appear anything like the "connetction pooling".
On the Internet I can not find the tutorial for the beginner.
Thanks.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:packagesToScan="com.history"
    p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="jpaProperties" ref="hibernateProperties" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true" />
    <property name="database" value="ORACLE" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" />
</bean>

<util:map id="hibernateProperties">
    <entry key="hibernate.connection.driver_class"
        value="org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider" />
    <entry key="connection.url" value="${dataSource.url}" />
    <entry key="connection.driver_class" value="${dataSource.driverClassName}" />
    <entry key="connection.username" value="${dataSource.username}" />
    <entry key="connection.password" value="${dataSource.password}" />
    <entry key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="100" />
    <entry key="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true" />
    <entry key="hibernate.order_updates" value="true" />
</util:map>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${dataSource.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${dataSource.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${dataSource.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${dataSource.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory">
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Hikari, you'll need to declare it, so your dataSource config should be

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${dataSource.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${dataSource.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${dataSource.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${dataSource.password}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks. Only need to do this? How to configure it? Where can I see all kinds of settings? Something I do not understand. Or do not need to configure anything?

Answer (score 0):

Your datasource config should be like this:

```
 <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource"  destroy-method="close">
                <beans:property name="dataSourceClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"/>
                <beans:property name="maximumPoolSize" value="5" />
                <beans:property name="maxLifetime" value="30000" />
                <beans:property name="idleTimeout" value="30000" />
                <beans:property name="dataSourceProperties">
                          <beans:props>
                              <beans:prop key="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/exampledb</beans:prop>
                              <beans:prop key="user">root</beans:prop>
                              <beans:prop key="password"></beans:prop>
                               <beans:prop key="prepStmtCacheSize">250</beans:prop>
                               <beans:prop key="prepStmtCacheSqlLimit">2048</beans:prop>
                               <beans:prop key="cachePrepStmts">true</beans:prop>
                               <beans:prop key="useServerPrepStmts">true</beans:prop>
                          </beans:props>
                </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Complete example with sample project to download can be found in link : 
http://frameworkonly.com/hikaricp-connection-pooling-in-spring-hibernate-jpa/

Answer (score 0):

We can also use it like below in customized JPAConfiguration class where you are establishing connection and creating entity Manager Factory object.

```
         import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig;
         import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;


        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            // In classpath from spring-boot-starter-web
            final Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("driverClassName", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            props.put("jdbcUrl", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/master?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true");
            props.put("username", "root");
            props.put("password", "mysql");
            HikariConfig hc = new HikariConfig(props);
            HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource(hc);
            return ds;
        }
```