# Does HikariCP need a different configuration when using with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, database-connection, hikaricp

When I'm using HikariCP 2.4.7 I typically initialize it like this:

```
hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();
hikariDataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
hikariDataSource.setUsername(DATABASE_USER_NAME);
hikariDataSource.setPassword(DATABASE_PASSWORD);
hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl(DATABASE_URL);
```

And when I need a connection:

```
 try(java.sql.Connection conn = hikariDataSource.getConnection()) {
            Record1 record1 = DSL.using(conn).select(SENSOR.ID)
                    .from(SENSOR)
                    .where(SENSOR.ID.equal(1))
                    .limit(1)
                    .fetchOne();
            System.out.println(record1.getValue(0).toString());
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Should I do something in another way or add something when using HikariCP with Spring Boot 1.4.0?

**Update 1:**

**build.gradle**

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.4.0.RELEASE")
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '1.4.0.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc', version: '1.4.0.RELEASE'
compile group: 'com.zaxxer', name: 'HikariCP', version: '2.4.7'
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=80
spring.datasource.hikari.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://someaddress.com:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.hikari.username=myservice_backend
spring.datasource.hikari.password=mypass
spring.datasource.hikari.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

However, after adding `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` and configuration in application.properties I get:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53695', transport: 'socket'

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.0.RELEASE)

2016-08-03 16:09:34.033  INFO 3492 --- [           main] pl.mypackage.Main                            : Starting Main on Defozo-laptop with PID 3492 (C:\Users\Defozo\IdeaProjects\myProject\build\classes\main started by Defozo in C:\Users\Defozo\IdeaProjects\myProject)
2016-08-03 16:09:34.038  INFO 3492 --- [           main] pl.mypackage.Main                            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-08-03 16:09:34.091  INFO 3492 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@f58853c: startup date [Wed Aug 03 16:09:34 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-08-03 16:09:35.298  INFO 3492 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]]
2016-08-03 16:09:35.820  INFO 3492 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b802c57c] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-08-03 16:09:36.484  INFO 3492 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 80 (http)
2016-08-03 16:09:36.501  INFO 3492 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-08-03 16:09:36.503  INFO 3492 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.4
2016-08-03 16:09:36.635  INFO 3492 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-08-03 16:09:36.635  INFO 3492 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2544 ms
2016-08-03 16:09:36.811  INFO 3492 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-08-03 16:09:36.814  INFO 3492 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-03 16:09:36.815  INFO 3492 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-03 16:09:36.815  INFO 3492 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-03 16:09:36.815  INFO 3492 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-03 16:09:36.863  WARN 3492 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
2016-08-03 16:09:36.874  INFO 3492 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2016-08-03 16:09:36.888  INFO 3492 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enable debug logging (start with --debug)


2016-08-03 16:09:36.896 ERROR 3492 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53695', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I've tried to change this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Main extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

to this:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Main extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

But still I'm getting the same output.

**Update 2:**

**application.properties**

```
server.port=80
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://someaddress.com:5432/mydb
spring.datasource.username=myservice_backend
spring.datasource.password=mypass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
```

**Console output:**

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50640', transport: 'socket'

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.0.RELEASE)

2016-08-04 12:55:49.369  INFO 11728 --- [           main] pl.mypackage.Main                            : Starting Main on Defozo-laptop with PID 11728 (C:\Users\Defozo\IdeaProjects\AirlyMap3\build\classes\main started by Defozo in C:\Users\Defozo\IdeaProjects\AirlyMap3)
2016-08-04 12:55:49.369  INFO 11728 --- [           main] pl.mypackage.Main                            : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-08-04 12:55:49.432  INFO 11728 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@f58853c: startup date [Thu Aug 04 12:55:49 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-08-04 12:55:50.786  INFO 11728 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'dataSource' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat; factoryMethodName=dataSource; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]]
2016-08-04 12:55:51.304  INFO 11728 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$932c4431] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-08-04 12:55:51.951  INFO 11728 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 80 (http)
2016-08-04 12:55:51.967  INFO 11728 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-08-04 12:55:51.969  INFO 11728 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.4
2016-08-04 12:55:52.114  INFO 11728 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-08-04 12:55:52.114  INFO 11728 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2682 ms
2016-08-04 12:55:52.315  INFO 11728 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-08-04 12:55:52.317  INFO 11728 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-04 12:55:52.317  INFO 11728 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-04 12:55:52.317  INFO 11728 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-04 12:55:52.317  INFO 11728 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-08-04 12:55:55.402  INFO 11728 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-08-04 12:55:55.418  INFO 11728 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2016-08-04 12:55:55.511  INFO 11728 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.9.Final}
2016-08-04 12:55:55.511  INFO 11728 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-08-04 12:55:55.511  INFO 11728 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-08-04 12:55:55.558  INFO 11728 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2016-08-04 12:55:56.751  INFO 11728 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
2016-08-04 12:56:48.037  INFO 11728 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2016-08-04 12:56:48.044  INFO 11728 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous : org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@6568f998
2016-08-04 12:56:48.738  INFO 11728 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@f58853c: startup date [Thu Aug 04 12:55:49 CEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-08-04 12:56:48.890  INFO 11728 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/v1/measurement],methods=[POST]}" onto void pl.mypackage.ResponseGenerator.sendMeasurementFromSensorToDatabase(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2016-08-04 12:56:48.891  INFO 11728 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/v1/measurements],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json || text/html]}" onto static org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> pl.mypackage.ResponseGenerator.getResponseAdequateToRequest(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>)
2016-08-04 12:56:48.895  INFO 11728 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-08-04 12:56:48.895  INFO 11728 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-08-04 12:56:48.924  INFO 11728 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-08-04 12:56:48.924  INFO 11728 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-08-04 12:56:48.988  INFO 11728 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-08-04 12:56:49.735  INFO 11728 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-08-04 12:56:49.795  INFO 11728 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 80 (http)
2016-08-04 12:56:49.800  INFO 11728 --- [           main] pl.mypackage.Main                            : Started Main in 60.881 seconds (JVM running for 61.327)
```

It started but it took it about 61 seconds to start. Why so long?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567127/hikari-connection-pooling-hibernate-4-3-8-spring-data-jpa-configuration) useful for you?

Comment: In my build.gradle file I have only: `compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.4.0.RELEASE")` from Spring Boot. Should I include any other modules from Spring Boot? Moreover, I don't have Hibernate, so does this post concerns me? If yes, where should I insert <bean> XML data?

Comment: You need to include the spring boot data jpa and jdbc starters. Then, include hikari and tell spring boot to use it, using `spring.datasource.hikari.*=` properties

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: `spring.datasource.hikari` defines only Hikari specific properties [starting from Spring Boot 1.4.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-1.4-Release-Notes#datasource-binding). The properties you're using are pool-library agnostic, so you should switch them to `spring.datasource`.

Comment: I changed it, but now the application starts a very long time.

Comment: Actually, why Spring Boot should know about HikariCP? Can they work separately not knowing about each other? What are (dis)advantages?

Comment: Spring Boot uses tomcat connection pooling by default. So it sets up a pooling even if you don't configure anything. This might suit your requirements. If you still want to use Hikari, yes, Spring Boot needs to know about it, just to set it up.

Comment: What Spring Boot is setting up in my Hikari? I just removed all lines from my application.properties and I am able to use Hikari.